# Connecting android application to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app that should retrieve data from sqlit database.  I have written a class with attributes that are needed for database and constructors, setter and getter functions. I also wrote the class for database handler as follows :

```
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context , String name, 
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_Books_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_Price + " FLOAT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_Books_TABLE);
 }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
    }

public void addbook(Books book) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, book.getName());
    values.put(KEY_Price, book.getprice());
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
        }

Books findbook(String name ) {
String query = "Select" + KEY_NAME + "FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + 
KEY_NAME + " =  \"" + name + "\"";

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Books book = new Books();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
     book.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    book.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    book.setprice(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)));
    return book;
 }
```

in the main activity i just done this :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this , null, null, 1);
    db.addbook(new Books("book1", (float) 5.50));        
    db.addbook(new Books("book2", (float) 4.30));        
    db.addbook(new Books("book3", (float) 5.85));        
   }

  public void SearchClickHandler(View view){
      DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this , null, null, 1);

            if (view.getId() == R.id.Searchbutton) {
        EditText BookN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bookname);
                         String Book_n = BookN.getText().toString() ;
        TextView resultT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLable);
                 Books book = db.findbook(Book_n);

                                 if(book != null ) {
            Log.d("Searching for your request ","please wait.."); 
                                    resultT.setText(Book_n + " is avaliable at our Bookstore, do you " +
                           "want to buy it ?");
             } else {
                 resultT.setText("We are soory,  "+ Book_n + "  is not avaliable at our Bookstore");
                                                        }
        }
 }
```

everything is fine and there is no error , the app run on emulator and device but when i click on search button
the application stops and exit..
so if anyone knows where is the error ?!

**EDIT :**
This is the stack trace for the code :

> 02-12 19:03:14.825: I/Choreographer(986): Skipped 506 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-12 19:03:16.475: D/AndroidRuntime(986): Shutting down VM
>   02-12 19:03:16.475: W/dalvikvm(986): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  ... 11 more
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.example.Bookstore.DatabaseHandler.findbook(DatabaseHandler.java:97)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.example.Bookstore.MainActivity.SearchClickHandler(MainActivity.java:50)
>   02-12 19:03:16.545: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  ... 14 more

**EDIT 2 :** 
This is the new stack trace for the code :

> 02-12 19:59:40.578: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1962): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   02-12 20:00:28.037: D/AndroidRuntime(1962): Shutting down VM
>   02-12 20:00:28.057: W/dalvikvm(1962): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
>   (group=0x414c4700)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of 
>   the activity
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
>   $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     ... 11 more
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: 
>   "book1"
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.example.Bookstore.DatabaseHandler.findbook
>   (DatabaseHandler.java:93)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.example.Bookstore.MainActivity.SearchClickHandler
>   (MainActivity.java:50)
>   02-12 20:00:28.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     ... 14 more

Comment: `there is no error` but `the application stops and exit`. not very consistent. post your stacktrace.

Comment: you missed 2 spaces in `"Select" + KEY_NAME + "FROM "`

Comment: i made the spaces but still have the same problem , i think database creation have wrong.

Comment: post your stacktrace.

Comment: I have added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

You're trying to access the first element in the cursor when the cursor is empty. You need to create and return your book object within the if(cursor.moveToFirst()) statement, not after it. Try changing your findbook method to this.

```
public Books findbook(String name ) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "  WHERE " + 
        KEY_NAME + " =  \"" + name + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            Books book = new Books();
            book.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            book.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setprice(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)));
            return book;
        }
        return null;
}
```

You're already handling the the null in your activity which is good.

Comment: This completely solve the scenario of wrong entry, But if i give it an entry exist in the database still aborting.

Comment: Are you getting a different stacktrace? If so please post it.

Comment: I found one more thing, you should use "Select * From" to get all the fields. I've updated my answer. You were only getting the name field but you're trying to access the Id, Name and price.